# gpg: keyserver receive failed

Tags: 20.04, gnupg, katoolin

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.ZXoflQHlR5/gpg.1.sh -qq --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.wELogVwz5k/gpg.1.sh -qq --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
This may be a server issue. Please try again later
```

This is what I get when trying to install `katoolin3` on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ sudo ./install.sh
[sudo] password for silentstorm:
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.LsQdt19RYD/gpg.1.sh -qq --keyserver pool.sks.keyservers.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.3JzK82pkYP/gpg.1.sh -qq --keyserver hkp.pool.sks.keyservers.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
This may be a server issue. Please try again later
```

Comment: gpg key for what? Which package? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: You need to ask a question first! Give us some context - hardware, Ubuntu version, how you ended up with that error message.

Answer (score 14):

> `--keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net`

SKS keyservers are deprecated and most of them are going offline. As such you will not be able to retrieve keys from them.

Instead you should use `--keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com`.

> No name This may be a server issue.

There is a notice dated 2021-06-21 on [sks-keyservers.net](https://sks-keyservers.net/) stating *"Due to even more GDPR takedown requests, the DNS records for the pool will no longer be provided at all."*

Comment: still not working

Comment: @justusgeorge it won't work because the install.sh script you're using was written to use the sks keyserver pool which no longer works.

Comment: Thanks. FInally I solved the issue by following command - 
`sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`